# Unable to install any app after updating ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, updates

I have ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop Dell inspiron 5558.It showed for updating and i clicked for update. During updating it showed some error. Now it is neither updating any more nor installing any apps.
The error message on my laptop is:

```
error:BrokenCount>0
```

Please tell me what to do so that i can install any app like before.